Wine Converted App (Fox Weiqi) Not Showing Chinese (or CJK) Characters
I'm able to run the Fox Weiqi client (the foreign version) perfectly with Wine.

And I can type and see CJK characters just fine on apps (I use FCITX).
Is Wine not able to access these characters by default?
It's also happening on my Mac (Sequoia).
I've just tried this other answer, but it got me some errors at the end of the install:
$ ./winetricks corefonts gdiplus riched20 riched30 wenquanyi     

...


10/10 12:20:17 [ERROR] CUID#7 - Download aborted. URI=https://web.archive.org/web/20160710055851if_/http://download.microsoft.com/download/WindowsInstaller/Install/2.0/NT45/EN-US/InstMsiW.exe
Exception: [AbstractCommand.cc:340] errorCode=2 Timeout.

10/10 12:20:17 [NOTICE] Download GID#e8dd5e0f2cd2c309 not complete: /home/phili/.cache/winetricks/msls31/InstMsiW.exe

Download Results:
gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
======+====+===========+=======================================================
e8dd5e|ERR |       0B/s|/home/phili/.cache/winetricks/msls31/InstMsiW.exe

Status Legend:
(ERR):error occurred.

aria2 will resume download if the transfer is restarted.
If there are any errors, then see the log file. See '-l' option in help/man page for details.
Executing cd /home/phili/.cache/winetricks/msls31
Downloading https://web.archive.org/web/2000/https://web.archive.org/web/20160710055851if_/http://download.microsoft.com/download/WindowsInstaller/Install/2.0/NT45/EN-US/InstMsiW.exe to /home/phili/.cache/winetricks/msls31

10/10 12:20:18 [NOTICE] Downloading 1 item(s)
[#fd45bf 0B/0B CN:1 DL:0B]                                                                            
10/10 12:21:03 [ERROR] CUID#7 - Download aborted. URI=https://web.archive.org/web/2000/https://web.archive.org/web/20160710055851if_/http://download.microsoft.com/download/WindowsInstaller/Install/2.0/NT45/EN-US/InstMsiW.exe
Exception: [AbstractCommand.cc:340] errorCode=2 Timeout.

10/10 12:21:03 [NOTICE] Download GID#fd45bfa35a4b4a14 not complete: /home/phili/.cache/winetricks/msls31/InstMsiW.exe

Download Results:
gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
======+====+===========+=======================================================
fd45bf|ERR |       0B/s|/home/phili/.cache/winetricks/msls31/InstMsiW.exe

Status Legend:
(ERR):error occurred.

aria2 will resume download if the transfer is restarted.
If there are any errors, then see the log file. See '-l' option in help/man page for details.
------------------------------------------------------
warning: Downloading https://web.archive.org/web/2000/https://web.archive.org/web/20160710055851if_/http://download.microsoft.com/download/WindowsInstaller/Install/2.0/NT45/EN-US/InstMsiW.exe failed
------------------------------------------------------

The later edit warns me about 32- vs 64-bit stuff:
./winetricks regedit                                                                             ─╯
Executing cd .
------------------------------------------------------
warning: You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
Using winetricks 20240105-next - sha256sum: 65d5aaffa155adcb1883aa71fb7e14a90a899dcac11e66e6ff368de40f3f0a79 with wine-9.19 and WINEARCH=win64
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/${LIB}/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/${LIB}/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/${LIB}/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

And, after reinstalling things, the program's layout got super messed up:

And now I'm not even sure how to revert this properly.
When I try to run the installer with Wine from the terminal, this is what I get, before finishing the install and going into the weird layout:

╭─    ~/Other Software/Fox Weiqi ────────────────────────────────────────────── ✔  16:33:08  ─╮
╰─ wine64 fox_install.exe                                                                           ─╯
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/${LIB}/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open 
shared object file): ignored.
0120:err:winediag:ntlm_check_version ntlm_auth was not found. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
0120:err:ntlm:ntlm_LsaApInitializePackage no NTLM support, expect problems
0120:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation HEAP_INFORMATION_CLASS 1 not implemented!
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/${LIB}/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

╭─    ~/Other Software/Fox Weiqi ─────────────────────────────────────── ✔  7s   16:33:46  ─╮
╰─ 0130:fixme:nls:RtlGetThreadPreferredUILanguages 00000034, 0259F6B8, 0259F728 0259F6C0            ─╯
0130:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x34 0x409 0259F6B8 0259F728 0259F6C0) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0130:err:winediag:ntlm_check_version ntlm_auth was not found. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
0130:err:ntlm:ntlm_LsaApInitializePackage no NTLM support, expect problems
0130:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation HEAP_INFORMATION_CLASS 1 not implemented!
0130:fixme:shcore:SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID L"Client.AppID.NoVersion": stub
0130:fixme:msvcrt:_set_abort_behavior _WRITE_CALL_REPORTFAULT unhandled
0130:fixme:nls:RtlGetThreadPreferredUILanguages 00000034, 0259F9E4, 0259FA54 0259F9EC
0130:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x34 0x409 0259F9E4 0259FA54 0259F9EC) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0130:fixme:shell:InitNetworkAddressControl stub
0130:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0130:fixme:win:RegisterTouchWindow hwnd 000200E4, flags 0 stub!
0174:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (1B0FFF10 00000000): stub
0130:fixme:win:RegisterTouchWindow hwnd 00010144, flags 0 stub!
0194:fixme:toolhelp:CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Unimplemented: heap list snapshot
0194:fixme:toolhelp:Heap32ListFirst : stub
0130:fixme:uxtheme:BufferedPaintInit Stub ()
01bc:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (29D7FF10 00000000): stub
0130:fixme:uxtheme:BufferedPaintUnInit Stub ()
0130:fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (78BEA300) stub
0130:fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (78886BE4) stub
0130:fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (7A510E54) stub


Have a look at this similar question.

@meuh Thank you for pointing me to that answer, but I think I messed things up more now T.T (see the edit)

I removed the winetricks version installed from wget, then installed it with pacman. And then I simply opened it to install fonts. Now I can see Chinese characters, but the argument error and the messed up layout still remain.

Anybody interested?

I don't have any experience with wine to help. You might try more searches throughout all the stackexchange sites, for example this search finds an Ubuntu question which might provide further insights to the problem.

User jkfloris on Wine Forums helped to solve the issues pretty much.

Create a Wine prefix: WINEPREFIX=~/foxweiqi wineboot
Install the necessary fonts: WINEPREFIX=~/foxweiqi winetricks -q tahoma fakechinese
Install the program: WINEPREFIX=~/foxweiqi wine install.exe
Enter the Windows-y folder: cd "${HOME}/foxweiqi/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/foxwq/foxwq"
Run the program: WINEPREFIX=~/foxweiqi wine foxwq.exe

For adding it back to Rofi, I had to create a script and reference it on the .desktop file, since running the program is now a 2-line thing, and I don't the syntax for it.
Now Fox Weiqi runs even better than the first time I ran it, with a proper layout. The only thing is that there are still some fonts not working, which I suspect emoji fonts (I did install the winetricks' allfonts package...).
